# Passing commas to key-value pairs with l3keys

Tags: l3keys

How can I pass commas to key-value pairs when using `l3keys` ?  Have inserted double quotes but the quotes get printed as well, something I do not want to appear.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\keys_define:nn { adr_keys }
  {
    name .tl_set:N = \l_name_tl,
    vltw .tl_set:N = \l_vltw_tl,
  }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \print_adr:n
  {
    \keys_set:nn { adr_keys } { #1 }

    \begin {tabular} { @{} l@{} }

      \tl_use:N \l_name_tl \\

      \tl_if_blank:VF \l_vltw_tl
        { \tl_use:N \l_vltw_tl \\ }

    \end {tabular}
  }

\NewDocumentCommand {\adr} { m }
  {
    \begin {flushright}
      \print_adr:n { #1 }
    \end {flushright}
  }

\ExplSyntaxOn

\begin{document}

\adr
  {
    name="Heime Borgia",
    vltw="405 Hilgard Ave, Los Angeles",
  }

\end{document}
```

Comment: Nothing to do with `expl3`: what made you think that quote marks would have any special meaning to TeX?

Comment: Was just an attempt.

Comment: You probably need braces around values which themselves contain a comma.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TeX's parsing rules mean that the way to 'hide' a token inside such delimited contexts is to use a `{...}` pair (assuming normal catcodes). This is unaffected by `expl3`.

```latex
\adr
  {
    name= Heime Borgia,
    vltw= {405 Hilgard Ave, Los Angeles},
  }
```

(It would be possible to have token-by-token parsing and pick up the `"` characters in a keyval context, but that would be slow and not needed here: we are dealing with input where expecting `{...}` treatment is reasonable.)